# How to fetch array inside another object using Axios?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, api, axios

that's my API, i want to fetch it using axios

```
[
    {
        "groupType": "Interessegruppe",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": "c42b0250-375e-4458-8f68-0df8179f889c",
                "name": "Teater",
                "assignmentStrategy": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "0fb94732-2bb1-483b-abbd-858327339ca0",
                "name": "Fotball",
                "assignmentStrategy": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "6b109ab1-5a3e-46b0-b0cc-e2b48d6e2dc6",
                "name": "Foto",
                "assignmentStrategy": 1
            }
        ]
    },

]
```

I wrote that code

```
      renderItem={({ item }) => <GroupCard title={item.groupType} subTitle={item.groups.name} />}
      />
```

and I fetched the groupType, but I can't fetch any of [ id or name]

Comment: `item.groups` is an array, so you need to use [list rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) (there is no `item.groups.name`, but there is `item.groups[0].name` for instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
async function loadData() {
    const data = await axios.get(url)
    return data[0].groups;
}
```

This function would return the groups array with `id` and `name` attributes.